# formatting `fewerBraces` does not always compile

Tags: intellij-idea, scala-3, intellij-scala

Since [Scala 3.3](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/releases/tag/3.3.0) `fewerBraces` [is a standard feature](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16297). However, when IDEA 2023.2 (Community Edition) with Scala Plugin 2023.2.19 formats the following code, the result does not compile.

```
class Foo(i: Int)(s: String)

val fooList: List[Foo] = Foo(42):
  """hi"""
:: Nil
```

After formatting:

```
class Foo(i: Int)(s: String)

val fooList: List[Foo] = Foo(42):
  """hi"""
    :: Nil
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? How to solve this?

**Edit 1:** I found the following **workaround**.

```
class Foo(i: Int)(s: String)

// @formatter:off
val fooList: List[Foo] = Foo(42):
  """hi"""
:: Nil
// @formatter:on
```

**Edit 2:** I reported a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-21539/bad-indentation-with-fewer-braces-and-a-list-or-seq)

Comment: I'd recommend you discuss this issue with the Scala plugin developers at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL

Comment: As @EgorKlepikov said, you can report an issue. Also in the [scala plugin github repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala) they said that you can also ask question in their [discrod channel](https://discord.gg/aUKpZzeHCK)